# What does "they" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

The following paragraph is from a book called "Conjectures and Refutations" by Karl Popper:

> "THE ESSAYS and lectures of which this book is composed are variations upon one very simple theme--the thesis *that we can learn from our mistakes*. **They develop a theory of knowledge and of its growth.** It is a theory of reason that assigns to rational argument the modest yet important role of criticizing our often mistaken attempts to solve our problems. And it is a theory of experience that assigns to our observations the equally modest and almost equally important role of tests which may help us in the discovery of our mistakes. Though it stresses our fallibility it does not resign itself to skepticism for it also stresses the fact that that knowledge can grow, and that science can progress-- just because we can learn from our mistakes."

My question is, does the pronoun "They" in "They develop a theory of knowledge and of its growth." refer to "mistakes" in "we can learn from our mistakes" or "THE ESSAYS and lectures"?

Comment: @Mrt which post on meta? :)

Answer (score 4):

> "THE ESSAYS and lectures of which this book is composed are variations upon one very simple theme--the thesis that we can learn from our mistakes. **They** develop a theory of knowledge and of its growth.

Let's examine both options (I've paraphrased them a little bit)

1. The essays in this book develop a theory of knowledge and of its growth.

or

2. Our mistakes develop a theory of knowledge and of its growth.

A series of essays could be used to [develop](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/develop) or 'to elaborate or expand in detail' a theory of knowledge and how knowledge grows.

Our mistakes can teach us important lessons, and may increase our personal knowledge, but they do not "expand in detail a theory of knowledge". We might think of a theory because of mistakes we've made, but then we would have to write essays or give lectures to explain our theory. It wouldn't be our mistakes that explain the theory.

I think you may already understand now that "They" refers to the essays and lectures, but I will write it out in case it's not clear.

Comment: Thanks very much ColleenV. I thought it goes back to "mistakes"!

Comment: @M.N I'm glad this was helpful. It might help your question if you edit it to explain what made you think it was mistakes instead of essays. Did I guess correctly that "develop" was a little confusing?